# Force to non-null without using?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, if I have the following:

```
val html = response.body()?.string()
```

html will compile to be nullable. I need to pass this to a function that does not allow nullables. Is there a way to pass it (or convert it) in a way that doesn't use !!

Comment: **What do you want `html` to be set to if `response.body()` returns null?**  That's why the expression could currently return null, and that's what you'll have to consider before you can work out what to change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either pass a default value, by using the elvis operator:

```
val html = response.body()?.string() ?: ""
nonNullableFunction(html)
```

Or, you could use `let` to call it only if `html` is not null. This will give you a nullable result from the function.

```
val result = response.body()?.string()?.let { nonNullableFunction(it) }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?:` to declare a default value that will be passed instead of `url` if `url` is `null`:

```
foo(url?: "default value")
```

You could also put this in your declaration so `html` will not be nullable:

```
val html = response.body()?.string()?: "default value"
```

As marstran pointed out you can also call your function inside a `let` block so it will only be called if `html` is not `null`:

```
html?.let{ foo(it) }//it is non-null
```